# Get Mount script from Azure file share - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

For every new `fileshare` that we create in `Azure Storage account` we get a `connect` option 
[image],

if we click `connect` we get the below options,

[image]

is it possible to get that piece of code to mount this fileshare through `terraform`? I could not find it anywhere. Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: You can't get this command from terraform, but, you can generate it and replace the hard-coded strings with variables, let me know if you would like an example

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it's possible. You just need to copy the code into a script and then use the VM extension to execute inside the VM. It's not complex at all. Here is an [example](http://hypernephelist.com/2019/06/25/azure-vm-custom-script-extensions-with-terraform.html).

But there is one thing you need to pay attention to, the VM extension only supports the non-interactive script. For example, the connect code for the Linux, the command `sudo` is an interactive command, so it's not recommended to use in the VM extension. You can get more details about the VM extension [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/overview).